# Где хранить исключения в джава-проекте?

Tags: java

Где в структуре джава проекта нужно хранить кастомные исключения? Создать для них одноименный пакет? Хранить каждое исключение в пакете с соответствующим классом, объект которого это исключение должен выбрасывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Специальных правил для этого нет.Если используете модульную структуру, то можно создать пакет под исключения и хранить их там.

Например, есть пакет модуля `com.example.module`. В нем создавайте подпакеты под каждый бизнес-домен.

- `com.example.module.service`
- `com.example.module.dao`
- `com.example.module.vo`
- `com.example.module.exception`
- и т.д.